# Only google drive recognizes audio file when sharing

Tags: android

With this snippet of code I share an audio:

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("audio/mp3");
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(
                "android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/raw/"+
                getResources().getResourceEntryName(audiosRage[position])));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Compartilhar via"));
```

They are contained in the 'raw' folder. I can send them through whatsapp, but in a format without extension that does not run. On the other hand, when saved on google drive, it recognizes it as a music file and runs, though it does not have extension. All audios in the raw folder are in .mp3 format

Comment: Few Android apps will recognize a `Uri` with an `android.resource` scheme.

Comment: What do you think I should do so I can share with Whatsapp?

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation for `EXTRA_STREAM`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_STREAM) says that you should use a `Uri` with a `content` scheme. So, for example, you could use `FileProvider` to serve up some local file that contains your audio.